# Is using the break room the only way to get some rest?

Tags: operate-now-hospital

I know if my staff run out of stamina, I can send them to the break room. Is that the only way for them to get stamina back? I only have one space in my break room, so it makes it hard to keep up with the needs of my staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are not at a post, then they will slowly regenerate. You can also apply consumables such as energy drinks, which will provide them with more stamina.